# reading values from properties.ini and getting file not found

Tags: command-line, dash-shell

I keep getting

```
./config.sh: line 5: .: properties_DEV.ini: file not found
```

When running `deployment.sh`, I am not sure why, all three files are in the same directory.

property file contains values, each file for each target env example: (`properties_DEV.ini`)

```
config_webApp_url=http://dev1
```

Then `config.sh` is loading this properties file and other configuration values:

```
#!/bin/sh
#target machine
installation_target_machine=DEV
#load specific machine properties file
. properties_${installation_target_machine}.ini
#Read a value from properties file
webApp_url=${config_webApp_url}
```

and last file is `deployment.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
# read the installation values from config.sh
. ./config.sh

#do stuff with target configuration
echo going to copyToUrl: ${webApp_url}
```

Update: add requested result

```
user1@dev:/tmp/test> ls -lb
total 12
-rwxr-x--- 1 user1 mqm 212 Jan 16 11:35 config.sh
-rwxr-x--- 1 user1 mqm 146 Jan 16 11:37 deployment.sh
-rw-r----- 1 user1 mqm  30 Jan 16 11:36 properties_DEV.ini

user1@dev:/tmp/test> ./deployment.sh
./config.sh: line 5: .: properties_DEV.ini: file not found
going to copyToUrl:
```

Comment: I created all three files, its just configuration information

Comment: Update: add requested result of   ls -lb

Comment: From which (working) directory are you executing `deployment.sh`?

Comment: same directory.

Comment: Are you really sure? Are you executing it as `./deployment.sh`? If not, how do you execute it?

Comment: yes, see edit...

Comment: Bash isn't involved here. `/bin/sh` is `dash`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're seeing here is the result of how the source command `.` in the POSIX `dash` shell handles unqualified filenames - which appears to be different from `bash` (at least, when it is in non-POSIX mode):

In `bash`, [the documented behavior for `source` (aka `.`)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) is:

> Read and execute commands from the *filename* argument in the current
>   shell context. If *filename* does not contain a slash, the `PATH` variable
>   is used to find filename. When Bash is not in POSIX mode, the current
>   directory is searched if *filename* is not found in `$PATH`.

In other words, `.` (or `source`) searches `PATH` *and then falls back to the current directory*. For example, given

```
$ cat > foo.sh
#!/bin/sh

bar=foo
```

then

## bash

```
$ echo "$bar"

$ . foo.sh
$ echo "$bar"
foo
```

However in `dash` the behavior is more like how executables are searched:

## dash

```
$ echo "$bar"

$ . foo.sh
sh: 2: .: foo.sh: not found
```

i.e. it does **not** fall back to the current directory after searching `PATH`; you need to prefix the filename with `./` explicitly:

```
$ . ./foo.sh
$ 
$ echo "$bar"
foo
```

---

TL;DR change

```
. properties_${installation_target_machine}.ini
```

to

```
. ./properties_${installation_target_machine}.ini
```

or use `#!/bin/bash` in place of `#!/bin/sh`